# where can i download simple code acl project in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, acl

i am beginner in cakephp and i need to correct and sample code for acl in cake.
i follow this tutorial :
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1543/Simple-Acl-controlled-Application

but i can't use well.
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out part 2 of this tutorial: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/tutorials/os-php-cake1/index.html

I found it useful, it walks you through exactly how to do it.